# Visual Studio: Configure Symbol Server via Registry

Tags: visual-studio, symbol-server

[Setting up Symbol Server in Visual Studio](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio) involves a lot of clickety-clack:

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General.
2. Uncheck “Enable Just My Code (Managed only)”.
3. Uncheck “Enable .NET Framework source stepping”. Yes, it is misleading, but if you don't, then Visual Studio will ignore your custom server order (see further on).
4. Check “Enable source server support”.
5. Uncheck “Require source files to exactly match the original version”
6. Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Symbols.
7. Select a folder for the local symbol/source cache.
8. Add symbol servers under “Symbol file (.pdb) locations”.

Is there any way to automate this rigamarole with a simple REG file or somesuch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved now (see how [Unplugged](http://beta.unpluggedhq.com/) does it):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Debugger]
"JustMyCode"=dword:00000000
"UseSourceServer"=dword:00000001
"UseDocumentChecksum"=dword:00000001
"SymbolUseMSSymbolServers"=dword:00000000
"FrameworkSourceServerName"="http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols"
"PublicSymbolServerName"=""
"PublicSymbolServerName2"=""
"SymbolPath"="http://beta.unpluggedhq.com/symbols"
"SymbolPathState"="1"
"SymbolCacheDir"="c:\symbols"
```